# How to get mount point of cgroups (control group) on RHEL/SUSE without using libcgroup's function?

Tags: c, linux, cgroups

I am trying to get mount point of cgroups on my RHEL & SUSE system.

[From This](https://github.com/matsumoto-r/libcgroup/blob/master/tests/get_mount_point.c) I am able to get it but it is with the use of libcgroup's system call. I have to do it without using any libcgroup library function as libcgroup may or may not be installed on customer's server.

Can any one please help?

Comment: Parse `/proc/cgroups` (using `getline()` and `fscanf()`), and `/proc/mounts` (using [`getmntent()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getmntent.3.html)) like [libcgroup](http://libcgroup.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.36-1/group__group__init_g37740e2f5f298edf13e18fcd7632b75a.html) itself does (or should do; using `fgets()` when you have `getline()` is just silly).

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks ...Really helpful